# How do I get my fish to face the right way?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, vector, oop

I'm making this 2d collecting game in Unity where you collect fish. However I can't get them to face the direction they are going. I've asked on some Discords and got no answer. Thanks in advance.

Here's is the [video of the fish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYWQA.jpg).

And here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float minY;
    public float maxY;
    public float minX;
    public float maxX;
    public float speed;
    public float maxZ;
    Vector2 targetPosition;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        targetPosition = GetRandomPosition();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if ((Vector2)transform.position != targetPosition)
        {
            transform.right = (Vector2)targetPosition;
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            
        } else { 
            targetPosition = GetRandomPosition();
        }
    }
    
    Vector2 GetRandomPosition()
    {
      float randomX = Random.Range(minX, maxX);
      float randomY = Random.Range(minY, maxY);
      return new Vector2(randomX, randomY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to point your local right vector toward the target, but you're assigning a *position* instead of a *direction*.

```
transform.right = (Vector2)targetPosition;
```

First, get the *direction* from your current position to your target.

```
var targetDirection = targetPosition - transform.position;
```

Then you can either assign this directly as you were trying to do before...

```
transform.right = (Vector2)targetDirection;
```

Or you can construct the specific rotation you want, something like this:

```
var upToTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, targetDirection);
var rightToUp = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90);
var rightToTarget = upToTarget * rightToUp;
```

You can now assign this rotation to your transform:

```
transform.rotation = rightToTarget;
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can also flip the sprite when facing to the left, so the fish doesn't end up upside-down, with something like:

```
spriteRenderer.flipX = targetDirection.x < 0f;
```