# Weapon flips upside down when aiming to the left

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, rotation, sprites

[image: Gun upside down aiming to the left]
[image: Gun right side up aiming to the right]

When the player turns to the left, the texture of the weapon turns upside down. How can I solve this?

**Shooting Script**

```
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _offset;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _prefabBullet;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _shootPoint;
    [SerializeField] private PlayerMove _playerMove;


    public void Shoot()
    {
        Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float rotateZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotateZ);
        Instantiate(_prefabBullet, _shootPoint.position, _shootPoint.rotation);
    }
}
```

**Movement script (only method here)**

```
private void Flip()
{
    // Switch the way the player is labelled as facing.
    m_FacingRight = !m_FacingRight;

    // Multiply the player's x local scale by -1.
    Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
    theScale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = theScale;
    //transform.Rotate (0f, 180f, 0f);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get my fish to face the right way?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/189878/39518) (Check at the bottom of the answer where it shows how to conditionally flip a sprite when facing left)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try doing the calculation in the parent's coordinate space instead, so it correctly flips when the parent does.

```
public void Shoot()
{
    // Get offset from gun to target, expressed in parent coordinate space.
    Vector3 worldTarget = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Vector3 localTarget = transform.parent.InverseTransformPoint(worldTarget);
    Vector3 localDifference = localTarget - transform.localPosition;

    // Take the perpendicular to this vector.
    Vector3 perp = new Vector3(localDifference.x, -localDifference.y, 0);
    
    // Aim the sprite so its up vector points at that perpendicular
    // (so its right vector points toward the target).
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, perp);

    // Spawn bullet.
    Instantiate(_prefabBullet, _shootPoint.position, _shootPoint.rotation);
}
```

I've also shown a trick to avoid doing the trigonometry manually. If the gun's "right" vector is meant to aim in the direction `localDifference`, then its "up" vector will point toward the perpendicular direction `perp`. We can construct a quaternion that points the up vector that way while keeping the forward vector pointing into the screen (so the sprite faces the camera), and assign that to the `localRotation` property without having to do any angle math or radian/degree conversions ourselves.